# How to install Oracle Developer Studio 12.6 in Solaris 11.3 (Intel x86)?

Tags: solaris, solaris-studio

I have installed Solaris 11.3 (Intel X86) from the Live DVD in a VM. Upgraded the fresh installation, no updates are pending. Added the Oracle Developer Studio publisher with the certificates as explained [here](https://pkg-register.oracle.com/register/product_info/6/). Made sure the `sunpro-incorporation` meta-package is up-to-date as explained by the [relevant Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E77782_01/html/E77785/gouaw.html#OSSIGgrzmw). Yes, I am at version `0.5.11-0.175.3.20.0.2.0`. Yes, I have installed the `developer-studio-utilities` package.

Despite all these efforts, I cannot install Developer Studio 12.6 (or 12.5, for that matter). Trying a "dry run" installation command `pkg install -nv developerstudio-126` fails with the following output:

> ```
> Creating Plan (Running solver): / pkg install: No solution was found
> to satisfy constraints
>
> maintained incorporations:  
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/SunVTS/SunVTS-incorporation@7.19.2-0.175.3.0.0.26.3
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/X/X-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.2.1489
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/admin/admin-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.1.0.0.5.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/cacao/cacao-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.24.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/cde/cde-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.16.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/cns/cns-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.24.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/dbtg/dbtg-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.29.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/ddt/ddt-incorporation@8.9.15.9.11  
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/desktop/desktop-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.28.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/desktop/gnome-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.26.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/gfx/gfx-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.1.0.0.5.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.26.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/java-7/java-7-incorporation@1.7.0.85.33-0 
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/java-8/java-8-incorporation@1.8.0.60.27-0 
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/jdmk/jdmk-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.2.0.0.22.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/l10n/l10n-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.26.2
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/man/man-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.28.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/nspg/nspg-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.1.0.0.5.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/nvidia/nvidia-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.17.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/osnet/osnet-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/sfw/sfw-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/sic_team/sic_team-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.20.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/solaris_re/solaris_re-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/ssm/ssm-incorporation@2.3.3.0-0.175.3.0.0.29.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.20.0.2.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/ub_javavm-6/ub_javavm-6-incorporation@1.6.0.999.99-0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/userland/userland-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.3.0
> pkg://solaris/consolidation/xvm/xvm-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.1.0.0.5.0
> pkg://solaris/entire@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.2
>
> Plan Creation: Package solver is unable to compute solution.
> Dependency analysis is unable to determine exact cause. Try specifying
> expected results to obtain more detailed error messages. Include
> specific version of packages you wish installed.
> ```

To my defense I'd like to mention that I have some Solaris admin experience going back to the Version 10 days, and this is not the first time I install Solaris packages. Have no idea what the problem is this time though. Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: What `pkg install -v` produces? It usually points out to missing packages. Also, how did you got version `0.175.3.20.0.2.0`? It seems like build #2, while publicly available build is `0.5.11-0.175.3.20.0.6.0`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Please see edited question. I have no idea how the version `0.2.0` got there, never saw any `0.6.0`. Trying to update `sunpro-incorporation` says I'm up to date.

Comment: You're having version of entire `pkg://solaris/entire@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.2`, so you don't have any updates installed. AFAIK some studio libs depend on libraries from SRU20, so unless you upgrade your system, developer studio cannot be installed (note that http://pkg.oracle.com doesn't provide updates)

Comment: I started from a fresh VM. I followed the instructions at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E77782_01/html/E77785/gouaw.html#OSSIGgrzmw to the letter. That webpage says "Example 2  Updating the sunpro-incorporation Package from the Oracle Solaris 11 Release Repository
This example shows that the release repository has been updated with a newer version of the sunpro-incorporation package (SRU20), and how to update the current build environment to that version of the sunpro-incorporation." I have version `0.5.11-0.175.3.20.0.2.0` at the end but still no "solution" computed.

Comment: If pkg.oracle.com does not provide updates, then who does? :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know if Solaris Updates are publicly available. I think the process is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E24456/gljrq.html#repose-1), though.

Comment: @myaut: The catch is that I have no Solaris support contract, and the page you were referring to explicitly says that "Oracle customers _with an active Oracle support plan_ [emphasis mine] have access to the support package repository". You can have Solaris free, you can have the compilers free -- but not together, apparently... :-)

Comment: I've checked docs, unfortunately SRU20 is a requirement. You might try to use tar archives for Solaris 10 to get right version of compiler (but you'll still need to install runtime libraries from IPS, I guess you'll get libraries from 12.5).

Comment: I was looking at the prerequisites a few days ago. Is your X86 machine Nehalem or above? (I can't install it because my Solaris machine has dual Xeon 3500's).

Comment: @jww It is a VMWare Fusion virtual machine. The host is a 2014 Mac Mini, with a quad-core i7 CPU. Definitely _not_ Xeon :-)

Comment: @user465139 - OK, it sounds like you are good. Nehalem is 1st gen Core; your Mini is probably somewhere around a 5th gen Core.

Comment: @user465139 - Also, Oracle is pretty shitty when it comes to patches and updates. I work on a free/open source project, and we only get access to the free and broken compilers. Oracle has released the 12.3 through 12.5 compilers with the same known bugs. For example, AES and GCM are broken without the compiler update patches (see [here](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/rijndael-simd.cpp#L51) and [here](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/gcm-simd.cpp#L21)). My contact at Oracle tells me he has no problems, but he gets the updated compilers from Oracle corporate.

Answer (score 1):

If you poke around the dependencies of `developerstudio-126` and try installing them one by one, you'll eventually find out that `developerstudio-126/dbx` requires `python-34` that is excluded by `userland-incorporation`. Then a search about "Solaris 11 incorporations" landed me on [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36802/gmias.html), which (albeit for Solaris 11.2) explains that you can disable the relevant `version-lock` facet here by running:

```
sudo pkg change-facet facet.version-lock.runtime/python-34=false
```

(This command obviously changes the configuration of the system to an unsupported state, so you may want to save a checkpoint of your virtual machine before running it.)

After disabling that particular facet, I was able to install `developerstudio-126` from the Package Manager without any more errors.

Answer (score 0):

We'll need a bit more information. What was the commandline you used to install Studio?  Also, do you still have the `solaris` publisher configured and have confirmed that you can install packages from it (for example, `system/header`)?

Comment: Thanks, question edited. Briefly yes, I can install from the `solaris` publisher. Commandline, see edited question.